# Old style fireplace ish

Tags: guitar

I wounder if there is a name for like the style of old people singing, music that i think fits the fireplace. Like sort of old man voice with guitar. Sorry for bad explanation, dont know how to express this.

Comment: theres  category of songs called campfire songs, but this is also for young people, do you mean something like this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean "campfire songs".

Answer (score 2):

Parlour songs, rather than campfire. There was an old tradition for people to sit around and sing popular songs of the day (and older songs) together, while the fire burned in the hearth. I used to play for these when I was alive (a long time ago), and consequentially learned a lot of good old songs on the way. Those were the days...

Answer (score 1):

One term that may cover the type of song you describe is "sentimental song."

That is a term applied in song books from the early 20th century.

The sentimental topics are usually things like dear, old mother's love, the beloved homeland, missing the home your grew up in, etc.

If that isn't exactly the song type you are thinking of, there are other common categories in such books: patriotic songs, college songs, minstrel songs, etc.

Some example books (the term is listed usually in a beginning table of contents, or index in the back.)

https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Book_of_a_Thousand_Songs/aKY9AQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&kptab=sideways

https://www.google.com/books/edition/Songs_every_one_should_know/37BMAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1

https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Ideal_Home_Music_Library_Sentimental/FbI2AQAAIAAJ?hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQ0vLbjaTlAhXIMd8KHau9DmUQiqUDMAx6BAgJEAg